# how to get query string with javascript and serialize it along with already serialized data?

Tags: javascript, url, serialization, get

I am serializing and stringyfing the form and appending it to the url query string using javascript.

```
var payload = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify($('formen').serialize(true)));
    var url_auth = window.superoffice_auth+"&redirect_url=" + encodeURIComponent(superoffice_auth_arg+"&settings="+payload);
```

The second thing is to get the query string and put it in payload which i can assign to the variable seetings.

How can i do that?

Comment: _I am serialized the form and sending a get request using javascript_ - where are you doing that?

Comment: I have edited the description, hope this will clear my query a bit more.

Comment: one issue I can see - `encodeURIComponent(superoffice_auth_arg+"&settings="+payload)` - you don't really want to do that

Comment: May i ask why shouldn't i use it?

Comment: because it's unusual to `encodeURIComponent` which includes a string that is the result of another `encodeURIComponent` and encoding `&settings=` means that the `&` and the `=` no longer mean what you think they mean ... but as I don't know your server side code, I can only speculate ... another issue is `$('formen`)` - you have a html tag called **formen** ?